# Destructure inside sort method javascript

Tags: javascript, sorting, parameter-passing, code-structure

I wrote a module that has sorting methods. I also tried to make it more flexible and destructure parameters to sort anything i will set creating object (more or less) but I don't know how to do it inside the sort method. What i tried is in the equal2 last method,  but obviesly is not working fine. Does anyone have clue what should i correct in this example?

```
 let products =  [ { name: "Grejpfrut", calories: 170, color: "czerwony", sold: 8200 },
{ name: "Pomarańcza", calories: 160, color: "pomarańczowy", sold: 12101 },
{ name: "Cola", calories: 210, color: "karmelowy", sold: 25412 },
{ name: "Cola dietetyczna", calories: 0, color: "karmelowy", sold: 43922 },
{ name: "Cytryna", calories: 200, color: "bezbarwny", sold: 14983 },
{ name: "Malina", calories: 180, color: "różowy", sold: 8200 },
{ name: "Piwo korzenne", calories: 200, color: "karmelowy", sold: 9909 },
{ name: "Woda", calories: 0, color: "bezbarwny", sold: 62123 }
];

  class compareSold {

     constructor(param1, param2) {
         this.param1 = param1 ;
         this.param2 = param2 ;
         // this.products = products ;
         const { calories, sold } = products;
         this.sortType = {
             asc: (param1, param2) => {
                 // console.log(param1);
                 if (param1.sold > param2.sold) {
                     return 1
                 } else if (param1.sold === param2.sold) {
                     return 0
                 } else {
                     return -1
                 }
             },
             dsc: (param1, param2) => {
                 // console.log(param1);

                 if (param2.sold > param1.sold) {
                     return 1
                 } else if (param1.sold === param2.sold) {
                     return 0
                 } else {
                     return -1
                 }
             },
             eqal: (param1, param2) => {
                 // console.log(param1);

                 if (param1.calories > param2.calories) {
                     return 1
                 } else if (param1.calories === param2.calories) {
                     console.log('a wowowiwa !!!');

                 } else {
                     return -1
                 }
             },
             eqal2: (param1, param2) => {
                 console.log(param1);

                 if (param1.sold > param2.sold) {
                     return 1
                 } else if ({sold} === {sold}) {
                     console.log('a wowowiwa !!!');

                 } else {
                     return -1
                 }
             }
         }
     }

  }

  const { calories, sold } = products; const compareSoldASCPass = new
 compareSold();

 // function calories ({calories}) { console.log(calories)}; //


 // Type of sorting(asc, dsc) ////////////////////////////////////////
 const compareSoldASC =
 products.sort(compareSoldASCPass.sortType.eqal2)

 // console.log(compareSoldASC);


 module.exports =  compareSoldASC;
```

Comment: Can you fix your question please?

Comment: Fix how? this is my first post so I'm not sure what is wrong what is right.

Comment: What are `compareSoldASCPass`, `compareSoldUp`, `compareSoldASC`? Please provide a code example that we can run without errors to see the problem.

Comment: Ok I made corrections. Here it is explenation: const compareSoldASCPass is a simply new Instance of compare sold, const compareSoldASC  is a method used on new instancein this spec situation is a method equal2 from compare sold class....  Code is working fine but my question is how to make destructure outside the class to pass specific arguments from products?

Comment: 1. `const { calories, sold } = products;` doesn't make any sense because products is an array 2. you don't need to pass anything to the constructor; the sort() method calls your functions and passes along the two parameters; you don't need them as instance variables and you don't need to destructure anything

Comment: Otherway what I am trying to reach is e.g: param1.calories > param2.calories change to param1 and pass the value calories outside the object

Comment: Yes that's right but I'm trying to make it more universal when i will have another array with e.g clothes [{size: 10, color:blue, etc.... }] and i would like to sort that array by size then i will have to change all methods in class (param1.sold > param2.sold) to (param1.size > param2.size).... is it posible to make it more scalable ??

Comment: Yes, take a look here: https://jsfiddle.net/khrismuc/mzft704b/

Comment: That is truly awesome thank You a lot Chris, my problem is solved.